# how to find model objects that belong to more than one model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have the models Book and Reading, which has the relationship Book has_many :readings.

Now suppose I want to find all books that have been read in the past week. I know I can find readings created in the past week with something like:
readings = Reading.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", Date.today - 7])

However, I'm not sure how to get from that list of readings to a de-duplicated list of books. I know I can't simply do readings.books because readings is an array and Array#books is not defined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.joins(:readings).group(:book_id).having("COUNT(*) > 1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know where I can find some documentation or tutorials related to the code you pasted? I'm a bit unfamiliar with those methods.

Comment: This is just how you'd do it in SQL translated into ActiveRecord. You may want to check out the ActiveRecord guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html